# Extra file generated while writing exporting collection to csv

Tags: geotools

I am exporting csv file from simple feature collection with help of gt-csv the feature collection is coming from db. Export is working fine but i am seeing another temp file generated  in the same folder with my table name as prefix and secondly is there any option available in this library so that i can put double quotes on string values.

```
 CSVDataStore csvStore = null;

    try
    {
          SimpleFeatureCollection coll = getCollectionDB();
        String geometryPropertyName;
        geometryPropertyName = coll.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
        File fileToSave = new File("Export.csv");

        Map<String, Object> cvsParams = new HashMap<>();
        cvsParams.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.FILE_PARAM.key, fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());
        cvsParams.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.STRATEGYP.key, CSVDataStoreFactory.WKT_STRATEGY);     
        cvsParams.put(CSVDataStoreFactory.WKTP.key, geometryPropertyName);
        csvStore = (CSVDataStore) DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(cvsParams);

        csvStore.createSchema(coll.getSchema()); 


        CSVFeatureStore csvFeatureStore = (CSVFeatureStore) csvStore.getFeatureSource(csvStore.getTypeName().getLocalPart());

        csvFeatureStore.addFeatures(coll);

    }
    finally {
        if(csvStore != null)
            csvStore.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: one question per question please. what is the content of the temp file?

Comment: what is the full name of the other file?

Comment: @IanTurton my table in postgres is "gistable" so file generated is gistable + randomNo i.e (gistable123456.......csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6175) cleaning up the temporary file the writer uses to allow you to back out of a write.

As for forcing quotes on text fields I don't think [`javacsv` 2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) which is the underlying mechanism we use to write out the data provides that functionality and even if it does it isn't currently exposed through the datastore. I've created an [improvement request](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6176) for an upgrade.

**UPDATE**

I've pushed a [fix](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2184).